# Find keywords in a substring using javascript/jquery - I'm getting a type error in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I need to create a script that will filter out content based on a list of keywords (if the content contains one of these keywords, I want to apply a style to it).

So far, I have this code:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].mcontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
    result = false;     
    theList = meta[3].split("','");

    var contents = (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || '')

    for (x=0;x<theList.length;x++) {
        if (contents.toLowerCase().indexOf(theList[x].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

$("div:mcontains('facer','non')").css("background","red")
```

I did not write this myself, I found it online, but I got it working fine the way I need it in a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtmVf/1/

However, when I try to port it into a project, I am getting this error in firebug:

```
TypeError: meta is undefined
```

On this line:

```
theList = meta[3].split("','");
```

I'm not sure why it's undefined there, but not throwing an error on the fiddle? There are no conflicts (I removed all other js except jquery.min in order to see if that was the issue).

I was hoping someone here would be able to see what I'm missing, what is wrong with this script?

Comment: Are you using the same version of jQuery in your project as in the fiddle?

Comment: @Chad: yes, I'm using the same version.

Comment: @wvxvw: I don't ind using native js if it's better, but this is the only code snippet I've found that does what I need. What are the more ophisticated parsing strategies?

Comment: try putting it in **$(document).ready(function() {...});**, or use a older version of jQuery, such as 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

post your code where you are assigning the "meta" array contents. Because these type of error usually shows when there is not such index in the array

Comment: It's above, the meta in this case is "'facer','non'": $("div:mcontains('facer','non')").css("background","red")